# What is limiting line in series spectrum?

Tags: wavelength, atomic-physics

> The wavelength of first line in the Balmer Series is 'whatever(in nm)' . Calculate
>   the wavelength of the second line and the 'limiting line' in the
>   Balmer Series.

I found this question in an ancient question paper in the library.

Now, I have solved the first part by calculating the atomic number from the first relation and then applying it while calculating the wavelengths of the second line in the Balmer series which must mean the line after Balmer (which is paschen). **But for the second part 'what is limiting line', and that's exactly what my question is. Also since the given wavelength is in 'nanometer' what whould be the unit of energy if found.**

I certainly don't need any solution for the above noted question( from the question paper),  so this question cannot be declared as an 'homework question' due to some weird rules, (ofcourse they are meant for a mass good,  but the tag name 'homework' hurts, anyway don't want that to be a topic of discussion here,  but please consider it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Balmer series is the light emitted when the electron moves from shell $n$ to shell 2. So the lowest energy line is emitted in the transition from $n = 3$ to $n = 2$, the next line is from $n = 4$ to $n = 2$, and so on.

But the energy does not keep going up as you increase the value of $n$, because the energies of the orbitals (wrt the vaccum) tend to zero for large $n$. So as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the energy released in moving from $n$ to $2$ will tend to a finite limit. This is the *limiting line*.

The Wikipedia article on the [Balmer series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series) gives [this value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series#Overview), so you may not want to read the article until you've had a go at calculating it.

To get the energy starting from the wavelength in metres, calculate the frequency using $\nu\lambda = c$, then the energy using $E = h\nu$.